# Completely inlining an AnyVal implicit class constructor without -Yopt-inline-heuristics:everything

Tags: scala, inline, inlining, scala-2.13

I'm experimenting with the Java 17 Vector API Incubator and I decided to see if I can create a zero-cost syntactic sugar for it. Here is a small snippet of what I wrote:

```scala
import jdk.incubator.vector._

object VectorOps {
  implicit final class FloatVectorOps @inline() (val _this: FloatVector) extends AnyVal {
    @inline def +(that: FloatVector): FloatVector = _this.add(that)
    @inline def apply(i: Int): Float = _this.lane(i)
  }
}

class Test {
  def test(x: Float, y: Float): Float = {
    import VectorOps._
    val SSE = FloatVector.SPECIES_128
    val xv = FloatVector.broadcast(SSE, x)
    val yv = FloatVector.broadcast(SSE, y)
    (xv + yv)(0) // sugar for xv.add(yv).lane(0)
  }
}
```

I'm using Scala 2.13.5 and Java 17.

Scala compiler is ran with `-optimize -opt:inline -opt-warnings:at-inline-failed -Yopt-inline-heuristics:at-inline-annotated -opt:nullness-tracking -opt:box-unbox -opt:copy-propagation -opt:unreachable-code -language:implicitConversions -opt:closure-invocations`

JVM is ran with `--add-modules jdk.incubator.vector`.

However, the Scala compiler compiles the final line of the `test` method to

```
    GETSTATIC VectorOps$FloatVectorOps$.MODULE$ : LVectorOps$FloatVectorOps$;
    POP
    GETSTATIC VectorOps$.MODULE$ : LVectorOps$;
    GETSTATIC VectorOps$FloatVectorOps$.MODULE$ : LVectorOps$FloatVectorOps$;
    POP
    GETSTATIC VectorOps$.MODULE$ : LVectorOps$;
    ALOAD 4
    INVOKEVIRTUAL VectorOps$.FloatVectorOps (Ljdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector;)Ljdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector;
    ALOAD 5
    INVOKEVIRTUAL jdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector.add (Ljdk/incubator/vector/Vector;)Ljdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL VectorOps$.FloatVectorOps (Ljdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector;)Ljdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector;
    ICONST_0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL jdk/incubator/vector/FloatVector.lane (I)F
    FRETURN
```

Those calls to the implicit class constructor completely throw Hotspot off and it's unable to unbox the vector variables, killing performance. Note that the implicit class constructor is, bytecode-wise, an identity function, which effectively means that it's a no-op. All the stuff with `MODULE$` is also unnecessary. But Hotspot does not see it.

(Note that the method calls to `+` and `apply` were successfully inlined.)

Adding `-Yopt-inline-heuristics:everything` removes both the constructor calls and `MODULE$`, and fixes performance, but it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. And like a sledgehammer, it doesn't feel safe.

Of course, writing the entire code in Java style also fixes the performance, but that's not the point.

So my questions:

1. Can the calls be eliminated without `-Yopt-inline-heuristics:everything` and without rewriting everything in the original Java syntax?
2. Scala 3 has some new inlining features. Can this be done in Scala 3 without aggressive optimization options?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you just need to write the `implicit class` without all those `@Inline`  and without using optimizer options from the compiler. For the compiler to transform those extension methods into function calls. - Now, if you also want to inline the function call to its body then I would recommend rather using `extension` and `inline` from **Scala 3**: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/9NZdsiShRFqoqx4pkOOJ3Q

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez In Scala 2, without `@inline` and optimization options, the code is even more peppered with unnecessary method calls, I want _zero_ calls to the implicit classes, all calls must be directly to the Vector API. Scala 3 looks promising. I gave it a try and there were no calls to inline extension methods, just like I wanted, however the vector performance is still awfully bad for some different, unexplained reason.

Comment: In **Scala 2** if you do: `implicit class FooOps(private val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal { def bar(x: Int): Int = foo.baz * x }` then doing: `foo.bar(10)` should be expanded by the compiler into `someFooOpsGeneratedBarMethod(foo, 10)`  if it does not, please submit a bug. - And, as I said, if you also want to avoid that extra method call and just have `foo.baz * 10` then you do need `inline` from **Scala 3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution: macros.

```scala
object VectorOps {
  implicit final class FloatVectorOps @inline() (val _this: FloatVector) extends AnyVal {
    @inline def +(that: FloatVector): FloatVector = macro MacroVectorOps.add
    @inline def apply(i: Int): Float = macro MacroVectorOps.lane
  }
}

object MacroVectorOps {
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
  def add(c: blackbox.Context)(that: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    // deconstruct the implicit conversion:
    val q"$conv($in)" = c.prefix.tree
    q"$in.add($that)"
  }  
  def lane(c: blackbox.Context)(i: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val q"$conv($in)" = c.prefix.tree
    q"$in.lane($i)"
  }
}
```

Code that uses this compiles to as efficient bytecode as if I wrote it using the original Java API, there are no traces of the FloatVectorOps class or VectorOps object in the bytecode at all.